# 2 buttons in android bar

Tags: rooting, home-button

Now I would like to have as few buttons in the android bar at the bottom as possible but I'm pretty sure both the back and home buttons are required. I believe this is true.

Could I assign the home button to activate the menu button on double click and just have the home and button button?  I'm rooted on 5.1.

Alternatively can I make Android activate home and back with volume up and down https://www.quora.com/Can-I-make-an-app-which-tracks-the-Android-volume-control-button-and-does-some-tasks-if-I-long-press-say-volume-up

[Picture of idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GplPh.png)

Comment: Sorry, missed that. You can have a look at [option 4](https://android.gadgethacks.com/news/best-apps-for-hiding-androids-soft-keys-reclaim-precious-screen-real-estate-0162519/). I don't think you can *reduce* the number of soft buttons though I could be wrong

Comment: This might work https://www.google.com/amp/www.addictivetips.com/android/ultimate-dynamic-navbar-for-android/amp/

Comment: Quite possible - it is similar to other options in earlier suggestion. Only reason for suggesting option 4 is that it retains flexibility of being hidden plus offering normal button option which the *muscle memory* remembers, though in a pie layout. Ultimately, it is your comfort level

Comment: Yet another option is Gravity Box Xposed module, which can be configured to hide when required and pulled up when needed. I use that on Marshmallow, with extra buttons for custom actions

Comment: Gravity Box has a bunch of out customisations and navigation bar is one part of it. Since device is rooted , this may help in customising your device in other ways too, instead of just having navigation bar focused app

Comment: The whole features that you want (modify navigation buttons & double-tap Home button) exist on LineageOS natively if you're willing to flash. Since I'm not sure how far you're willing to do, I just put it as a comment first, not an answer... (also, I think there's a typo on second paragraph: "*home and **button** button*"?)

Comment: @AndrewT could you provide a link so I could read about it

Comment: [Navigation Bar Tweaks](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-nougat-how-to-enable-hidden-navigation-bar-tweaks/) (apparently it's from N Developer Preview) and [Home Button Double Tap](https://forums.oneplus.net/attachments/screenshot_20160630-201138-png.445158/) (image from OnePlus device; CyanogenOS/CyanogenMod). Source: I'm using LineageOS 14.1 on Nexus 5. Now, since you didn't mention your device model, I'm afraid if LineageOS doesn't support your device...

Comment: @AndrewT Motorola moto G. I believe it is supported

Comment: "Now I would like to have as few buttons in the android bar at the bottom as possible" - so can you just hide the bar and use something floating on-screen like [LMT](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330150)?

Comment: @AndyYan Could I define the 3 buttons to activate depending on where I swipe from bottom maybe?  I'm not sure of the right name for this but maybe hot spots that separate the bottom screen into three places.

Comment: Never heard of such implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am self answering this can all be done using Lineage OS.  Install Lineage 
OS then go under Settings->Buttons->Buttons & Layout.  You then can add and remove buttons to your hearts content.  Once you are done change Home double tap action to activate Recent apps switcher.